# __LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD and __BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to know what compiler of kernel will do with different endian bitfield:

```
struct iphdr {
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
__u8
    ihl:4,
    version:4;
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
__u8
    version:4,
    ihl:4;
#else
    #error "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
#endif
......
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure `iphdr` takes up 1 byte.  In a little endian machine, the first field `ihl` occupies bits 0,1,2,3 and the 2nd field `version` occupies bits 4,5,6,7.  `ihl` is listed first and  gets the least significant bits.  In the seconds case, `version`, being listed first gets the first bits.  Since this is big endian, the first bits are bits 7,6,5,4.  `ihl` get the next four bits, 3,2,1,0.

With the #if condition, regardless is one compiles in a big or little endian machine, the bits are in the *same* bit offset location within a byte.

With these field in the same bit localization, various masking and bit shift operations give the same result.

---

Interestingly the phrase little endian and big endian originate for the the story *Gulliver's Travels*.  There, folks argue a senseless war about which end of a hard-boiled egg to crack first.  Thus big endian vs. little endian.  An apt name for a senseless debate about which is more correct.  (I'm a little endian-er.)

---

Further, the same story introduces another computer term: yahoo.