# Having trouble understanding ip structure implementation

Tags: c, linux, ip, structure, endianness

While I was experimenting on structure concept in C, I was checking how IP header was implemented so i just found in the internet the below declaration.

```
struct iphdr {
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    ihl:4,
        version:4;
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    version:4,
        ihl:4;
#else
#error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
#endif
    __u8    tos;
    __u16   tot_len;
    __u16   id;
    __u16   frag_off;
    __u8    ttl;
    __u8    protocol;
    __u16   check;
    __u32   saddr;
    __u32   daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
};
```

I just want to know in case of little endian why **ihl** comes before **version**. w.r.t little endian the **least significant bits** will be stored at **lower memory location** in that case version could be defined first why it is defined after **ihl**.

I have done below expt please help me to understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct my_iphdr {
    unsigned char ver:4;
    unsigned char ihl:4;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_iphdr ip;
    ip.ver = 0;
    ip.ihl = 15;

    char * ptr = &ip;

    printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)*ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using little endian machine

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              12
```

I have got the o/p 240 i.e 11110000 in that case the **ver** stored in lower bits and after de-reference I am able to see proper value then why **ihl** comes before **ver**.

Comment: this guy said it better than I could:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070977/little-endian-bitfield-and-big-endian-bitfield hope this helps

Comment: @Farkash Thank you for replay it means a lot. here my question is if we google IP frame format the first field is version so in case of little endian the first 4 bits should be version field right? why 'ihl' came first? in this case first 4 bits will be taken as 'ihl' not the version as in frame format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why bit endianness is an issue in bitfields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields)

Answer (score 0):

One way to understand this is by referring to the IP header, here is [a link](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40506/in-ipv4-does-the-identification-field-in-a-tcp-packet-change-for-fragmented-pack#55537) to an ip header.

`ihl` field is the first ever field of the IP header therefore it needs to be read first when reading the IP header:

- Big endian: The most significant byte (which is `ihl`) is stored first. Thus logically the `ihl` field ***will be defined first so it can be stored first in memory***
- Little endian: The least significant byte (which is `version`) is stored first. Thus `version` field will be defined before `ihl`.