Does gcc compiled executable LSB imply "Least Significant Byte" and "Least Significant bit" at the same time?
I want to know how is the bit order of an int32_t is stored in memory, so I write some code to print.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

void print_i8_as_bits(int8_t num) {
  #pragma pack(1)
  struct Byte {
    unsigned bit_0: 1;
    unsigned bit_1: 1;
    unsigned bit_2: 1;
    unsigned bit_3: 1;
    unsigned bit_4: 1;
    unsigned bit_5: 1;
    unsigned bit_6: 1;
    unsigned bit_7: 1;
  };
  #pragma pack()
  assert(sizeof(struct Byte) == 1); // your compiler didn't not support #pragma pack(), try gcc

  struct Byte *byte = (struct Byte*) &num;
  printf(
    "%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u",
    byte->bit_0,
    byte->bit_1,
    byte->bit_2,
    byte->bit_3,
    byte->bit_4,
    byte->bit_5,
    byte->bit_6,
    byte->bit_7
  );
}

void print_i32_as_bits(int32_t num) {
  int8_t *bytes = (int8_t*) &num;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    print_i8_as_bits(bytes[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }
}

int main() {
  int32_t num = 3;
  print_i32_as_bits(num);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}

// the result is the same in my computer
void print_i8_as_bits_impl_2(int8_t num) {
  int8_t bit_0 = num & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_1 = num >> 1 & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_2 = num >> 2 & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_3 = num >> 3 & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_4 = num >> 4 & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_5 = num >> 5 & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_6 = num >> 6 & 0b1;
  int8_t bit_7 = num >> 7 & 0b1;
  printf("%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u", bit_0, bit_1, bit_2, bit_3, bit_4, bit_5, bit_6, bit_7);
}

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

$ gcc print_bitfields.c && ./a.out
11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

$ file ./a.out
./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64,
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,
interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
BuildID[sha1]=ec61c8110d755b9b9216325536bcd1bcdc36cf1b,
for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped

Originally, I wrongly expect the output to be: 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000
But it's: 11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
So I have a search and found this:

With GCC, big endian machines lay out the bits big end first and little endian machines lay out the bits little end first.

But it didn't have external link.
Can I assume gcc compiled LSB executable imply "Least Significant Byte" and "Least Significant bit" at the same time?
Or it is just a specific behavior of gcc on x86_64 computer?
[Note]: LSB = Least Significant Byte first = little endian

C does not oblige bit endian and byte endian to be the same.  The higher level issue is: why it it important for you as good code does not rely on such assumptions?

You seem to be assuming that bit 0 is the most significant bit. I'm accustomed to the convention that bit 0 is the least significant bit. Since you start printing from bit 0 , your results match my expectations. Low bit of 3 is a 1. But that may not help much. The compiler has a lot of latitude in how it lays out bit fields. I don't think that your code can be guaranteed to make the determination you want it to.

@chux-ReinstateMonica It's not a big deal. But the printed result surprise me, so I'm curious.

Important note: your link is talking about layout of bit fields  , not "bit order of an int32_t is stored in memory"

@cpprust OK.  Yet if a particular order was desired, one can code for that goal regardless of integer endian or struct implementation details via shifts, etc.  Well written code with a good compiler would emit efficient code that does not rely on assumptions.  Consider that approach instead of bitfields and casts.

@AviBerger Thanks, I haven't thought so. And if compiler make the least significant bit comes first, cast to smaller type can just cut off the most significant bits, which make sense.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I got it, do this via bit shifts if more portable. But if it is more efficient to use bitfields and casting if I am writing very bad code and assume the code will only compile in gcc?

@cpprust Use your valuable time to write portable code and consider bitfields/casting only after you have demonstrated that the portable code approach was weak. Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?

See this question about bit order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924045/byte-vs-bit-order-in-endianess


With GCC, big endian machines lay out the bits big end first and little endian machines lay out the bits little end first.

Not defined by the C standard and probably not even defined by the gcc documentation.

Can I assume gcc compiled LSB executable imply "Least Significant Byte" and "Least Significant bit" at the same time?

No.

Or it is just a specific behavior of gcc on x86_64 computer?

If it is even that. You'll have to dig up info about the x86 port in the gcc documentation to see how it implement bit-fields. If such documentation even exists...

There are two ways in C which allows you to access individual bits. One is bit masking and shifting, data & (1u << n). The other is bit-fields.
In case of bit masking/shifting, the code is portable. data & (1u << 0) is guaranteed to give you the least significant bit (bit 0) of the data regardless of things like endianness.
In case of bit-fields, the code is 100% compiler-specific with no relation to the underlying hardware what-so-ever. The C standard only vaguely defines bit-fields, leaving a whole lot of details to the compiler. In particular, it does not define things like bit order, byte order, padding bytes, how bit-field chunks may overlap each other. It does not even define what will happen if you declare a bit-field of type int32_t or long etc.
So the only thing your code shows is "gcc supports some manner of bit-fields and this is how one particular gcc port implemented them". That tells us absolutely nothing about the underlying hardware. Making bit-fields pretty much useless for any purpose other than declaring a chunk of bit flags that we don't know/care about how they are stored in memory.
Meaning that bit-fields should pretty much never be used for any purpose - it is a broken part of the C language.

Bit order inside of a byte is not a thing, it's impossible to determine because the individual bits are not addressable.
Best you can do is the order of bytes inside of a larger scalar, because bytes are addressable.

This behavior of GCC (endiannesss controlling the bit order for bitfields) is arbitrary and doesn't reveal anything about the hardware.
It's just convenient, because it means that if you reinterpret the adjacent bitfields as a single scalar (of their underlying type), each bitfield ends up occupying contiguous bits, and the order of bitfield declarations matches the their order in the underlying scalar (or the reverse of that on big endian?).

Do you mean the bit order is not defined by C standard, architecture and GCC, how to interpret the meaning of the bits in a byte is a randomly hard-coded behavior of my current GCC? It's just an phenomenon occur in my specific version of GCC and may not occur in other version of GCC?

@cpprust There are two different things here: bit order in bytes (on hardware level), and the order of bitfields (as chosen by GCC). The former can't exist in the first place, because there is absolutely no way to check the supposed "bit order", because there's no way to grab a bit by its index from memory, only a whole byte. The latter isn't defined by architecture and C standard, and is defined by GCC (and probably the platform's ABI). You can't use the latter to judge about the former.

It would make no sense for anything to have least-significant bits print first. This convention is strong and deeply culturally rooted. Just like in the decimal number 12345 means 5 is the least significant digit, there is no debate or confusion as to whether this number could also be represented as 54321. Nobody does that.
Byte order was significant for some hardware architectures; because of how the processor accessed memory, it made sense for a number which took up multiple addresses in memory to have the addresses arranged so that the first one contained the least significant portion.
Just to spell this out, to store the decimal number 12345 on a system with 8-bit bytes and 16-bit integers, you would have to split it up into two bytes. By convention we represent these hexadecimally; the number is 0x3039 and so you break it up into 0x30 and 0x39 (or in binary, 00110000 and 00111001). To store this number at memory address x, you would store 0x30 at address x and 0x39 at x + 1 on a big-endian system, and vice versa on little-endian.

"convention is strong and deeply culturally rooted." --> It is interesting that English uses seventeen (seven and ten) for 17: little endian for text and big endian for numeric.  Sometime s cultural things are not so consistent.

That's only for the teens in English though. You say twenty-one and a hundred and six. In German the first would be ein und zwanzig but the hundreds and up are still big-endian. (E.g. Danish is somewhat crazier still.)

(Joining the fray) It's easy to load a small BMP file into an array... The low value indices reference the bottom pixels of the image, while the high value indices are used to access the top pixels of the image (usually)... Just something the man-in-the-street wouldn't assume to be the case. :-)

@tripleee The meaning of sequence of bits in byte is decided by how the computer interprets it. I want to know it's decided by the architecture or the compiler?

It doesn't make any real difference how things are stored on the hardware level. All you care about is if you put in 0x39 you get back 0x39 when you read it. You would absolutely not want to get back 0xC7 or whatever. And arithmetic etc would become quite cumbersome if 1 + 1 != 2 any longer.

@tripleee I don't under stand why do you say "It would make no sense for anything to have least-significant bits print first." The LSb is printed first in my code.

Of course it does because you made it do that. It still makes no sense.
